# Open/SaveAs dialogs in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, npapi

I thought that it is impossible to work with Open/SaveAs dialogs in chrome extension and because of that I created npapi plugin for it.
But my extension has been rejected when I tried to publish it. So IT IS possible to work with Open/SaveAs dialogs from javascript in chrome extension, otherwise they woudn't block npapi plugins, right?
Okay, my question is How to work with Open/SaveAs dialogs in chrome extension?
Thanks :)

Comment: While I don't yet have an answer to your open/save as question, I know that Chrome is removing support for NPAPI in January: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html